# Can I connect Windows 8 to a Server 2000 domain?

Tags: windows-8

I manage a network of varied PCs (WinXP, Win7Pro, Linux) on a Windows Advanced Server domain (thru AD).  I've updated my Samsung Series 7 Slate from Windows 7 Pro to Windows 8 Pro.  I've yet to try but wanted to know if it's possible to logon to the Windows 2000 Adv Server domain as my other PCs do?

Comment: Why not give it a try and report back? It should only take a couple of minutes to work out, no?

Answer (score -1):

This is the only way I managed to overcome this issue.

I find it very appalling that something so basic and simple has to have such an unintuitive solution.

Kudos to the guy at Eureka.

http://ykyuen.wordpress.com/2009/09/04/windows-7-cannot-connect-to-newtork-drive/#comment-70

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.superuser.com/faq) for more info.